# Go setup on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, go

I am trying to setup a go dev environment on Ubuntu, and having no luck. Following directions here https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install golang
```

Then I

```
mkdir $HOME/golang
export GOPATH=$HOME/golang
```

No dice. Even doing something simple like `go version` throws the following error:

```
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/opt/go/libexec
```

Everywhere I look online says simply not to set `GOROOT`. Please help, I don't understand where to go from here. This is a fresh install on a fresh VM.

---

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/isaac/golang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: What does `go env` print?

Comment: Added to my question

Comment: This is a very odd GOROOT. On my Ubuntu 14.04 it installs go to `/usr/lib/go`. Are you sure you haven't set GOROOT anywhere? `env | grep GOROOT`?

Comment: Yes. GOROOT was set from `apt-get install`

Comment: That also looks like an out of date package. I would forgo the official apt repos and use the standard methods for installation https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: Install the official stuff from golang.org.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I eventually figured this out, and boy was it dumb on my part. I had a script that was effecting `$GOROOT`, and learned alot. Here are the big lessons:

- Do NOT use `sudo apt-get install golang` it is out of date and doing so means you now have to revert the install. `sudo apt-get install golang-go` is also out of date. Just don't use `apt-get`.
- `sudo apt-get purge golang` does not reset environment variables or delete all go related folders.
- `unset GOPATH GOHOME GOROOT` is important cleanup before trying another install
- ONLY install via `tar.gz` from the golang website
- GOROOT means the folder where go's internal files live, so basically where ever the contents of the `tar.gz` lives on your system. Typically `/usr/local/go`
- GOHOME does not need to be set. If you set it, use `unset`
- GOPATH is the location of your workspace, you need to `mkdir` to create that folder as well as set the GOPATH environment variable.
- Your path needs to included `$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin` for the setup to function.

Usage of custom scripts that effect `.zshrc` or `bashrc` or `profile` should not contain setting of `$GOROOT`!!

Answer (score 10):

On my ubuntu machine i installed go by following those simple steps:

```
$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
$ rm go1.4.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Add go to your $PATH variable

```
$ mkdir $HOME/go
$ nano ~/.bashrc
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

This Works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

#### For golang-go from the Ubuntu repositories

This answer refers to the golang-go package from the default Ubuntu repositories, not the go-lang package that can be installed using ubuntu-make.

The key to understanding your question is the following line:

```
GOROOT="/usr/local/opt/go/libexec"
```

If you typed the command `echo $GOROOT` it would return:

```
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
```

This is not what you want GOROOT to be in an installation of golang-go from the default Ubuntu repositories. In a default golang-go installation in Ubuntu GOROOT refers to the root of the directories where go is installed. Running the command `which go` returns `/usr/bin/go` and examining the `/usr/bin/go` file reveals that it is symlinked to the go executable file located at `/usr/lib/go-1.6/bin/go` . There is your missing GOROOT. If you installed golang-go using the command `sudo apt install golang-go` GOROOT is the root directory of all the go files that are installed by golang-go; it is `/usr/lib/go-1.6` !

It remains to apply the change in GOROOT to `/etc/environment` by editing the environment file in nano text editor with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Right after where it says `PATH="` in `/etc/environment` insert the following text to add it to the PATH:

```
/usr/lib/go-1.6:
```

Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited in nano to its current location. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

The `:` character after `/usr/lib/go-1.6` is the delimiter character which separates the go path from the next path. It is advisable to check your work for accuracy with the following command:

```
cat /etc/environment
```

Now that you have updated the PATH you need to reload `/etc/environment` by logging out and logging back in.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @sadlil's answer, you can have a compound `GOPATH`. You might have a separate directory where you have all your projects and you want to keep this directory structure. Create a go directory in your `all_projects` directory and append it to the `GOPATH`.

This is my `.bashrc`.

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
export GOPATH=$GOPATH:$HOME/all_projects/go  # add projects directory
```

Another point to note is that go prefers a specific directory structure. For e.g. if you are working on a project you host at github.com, you can have the following directory structure.

```
   go
   |-bin
   |-pkg
   |-src
   |---github.com
   |-----username
   |-------reponame
```

This [youtube video](https://youtu.be/PGq6CPff2EY) was very helpful in setting up VS Code for go.